# Python, Django 'function' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

Hi I got this problem when accessing database:

> ```
> AttributeError at /renderForm/0
> 'function' object has no attribute 'all'
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/renderForm/0
> Django Version: 1.2.5
> Exception Type: AttributeError
> Exception Value:    
> 'function' object has no attribute 'all'
> Exception Location: /home/jay/projects/work/newForm/f/apps/main/views.py in createWholeForm, line 16
> Python Executable:  /home/jay/projects/work/newForm/bin/python
> Python Version: 2.7.1
> Python Path:    ['/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/f/apps', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/f', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/jay/projects/work/newForm/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
> Server time:    Fri, 20 Jan 2012 18:52:31 -0600
> ```

when I try to do this in django:

```
form = Form.objects.get.all()
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `get` function does not have an `all` attribute. The model manager `objects` has the `all` function you're looking for:  `Form.objects.all()`